# meta-analysis when the control value is taken from a standard (iso, en, etc...) and do has not any variance

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, standardized-mean-difference

I am starting to conduct a meta-analysis on the effect of different raw materials on pellets quality (for bioenergy purposes) I have already the database of studies and my idea initially was to calculate standardized mean difference effect size using the value of "alternatve biomass" pellet (treatment) compared with the one of a "typical/commercial" pellet (control). However many studies in my database do not report any control pellet. Therefore I am thinking about using as control the values taken from the technical ISO regulation for pellets quality. In this way I will compare the value of the "alternative" pellet with the value from the standard... the problem is that the standard did not report any variance (SE, SD; CI), for example heating value has to be higher than XX MJ/kg... do you know how to manage this issue and calculate effect sizes that can be subsequently grouped by meta-analysis?